# R - creating a function f(x) as a sum indexed by n

Tags: r, function, recursion

Is it possible in R to write a function f(x) like

```
f(x) = a_0 + a_1*sin(x) + ... + a_n*sin(n*x)
```

for some n, or any other f_i(x) in place of sin(i*x) just varying on i? I tried a recursion like

```
f <- function(x) a_0
for(n in 1:N)
f <- function(x) f(x) + a_n*x^n
```

It seemed to work but when I used f(x) to make some computations R said there was too much nesting. I eventually wrote by hand a_0 + a_1*x + ... etc.
Is there a proper way to do it in a compact way without using recursion?

Comment: Sorry， I can't load the image, can you express it with some words?

Comment: You seem to be redefining the function `f` in a loop and I'm not sure that's what you want. What is some sample input to this function and what is the value you expect to be returned for that sample input. Is `f` a function of both `a` and `x`?

Comment: This `f <- function(x) a_0` makes  no sense, it's necessary because it's just a constant.  Is your purpose  to calculate `f(x) = a_0 + a_1 * x + ... + a_n * x^n `?

Comment: @PeaceWang I need to define a function like for example f(x) = a_0 + a_1*sin(x)+ ... + a_n*sin(n*x) for some n, so then I can compose it with other functions or integrate it etc.

Comment: @MrFlick I guess my last comment explains better what I'm asking.

Comment: So where are the values of `a` coming from? It seems like you can just do `sum(a*sin(x * seq_along(x))` assuming `a` is a vector the same length as `x`. And then just add the null term. It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick I'm confused! a is a given vector a_0, ... , a_N, but x is a variable in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the following values of `a` and `x`

```
a <- 1:5
x <- 3
a[1] + a[2]*sin(x*1) + a[3]*sin(x*2) + a[4]*sin(x*3) + a[5]*sin(x*4)
# [1] -0.5903971
```

Then you can get the same value using

```
f <- function(x) {
  a[1] + sum( a[-1] * sin((x * seq.int(length(a)-1) )))
}
f(x) 
#[1] -0.5903971
```

Note that arrays in R use 1-based indexing